# How to Auto-Generate a Craft Commerce Product Title

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, titles, auto-generate

How can I auto-generate the product titles in Craft Commerce? I'd like to auto-generate it from the post date and a custom field value. I can see how to auto-generate the SKU, but can't see how to do this for the product titles in the same way (like you can do for normal Craft entry titles).

I asked about this in the Craft Commerce Slack but didn't get a response, so just asking the question here instead. Thanks in advance for any help or possible workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the Variant titles automatically, but not for top level Product Types:

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason Pixel & Tonic didn't allow this for top level product names? I have a series of 3 fields that require specific numbers and data that would actually be the same as the title of the product, so it would be ideal to auto generate the title of the product from these fields (ala other craft sections).

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request for this on GitHub. So suggest you go and 'up-vote' it on there to try and get this released.

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/148